# Question regarding first complex

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

Okay, I finally got my first 3.5 Million Euro in the game after starting as bankrupt assasin.
Now I want to invest them wisely.

### My Plan:

- Ranch M 275.000€
- Cahoona Press M 880.000€
- Mosquito Rocket Factory 603.000€
- 3x Complex Parts 780.000€
- Renting a TL Peanuts
- Total: 2.538.000€

So far so good, can buy a trader afterwards and still have some money left.
I planned on building it in "Line of Energy" (hopefully I translated it correctly), so I can add a E-Cell Factory later since it is 2.6 Million for that one alone.

Can anyone recommend that approach?

How far/close from/to each other do I have to build the factories in order to make them a complex?

Thanks for any input.

> edit:

I did it how I wrote it here, thanks for all help.
As reference for other people that seek help:
The complex ran fine with 2 Commercial Agents from the Bonus Package. That is Trade Command Software Mk2. I was continuing Missions and earning from that factory. As soon as I could, I added a Solar Power Plant. From that date on, the complex ran fine with 1 Commercial Agent, while the AI brought me crystals and ore +. Turning 1 off is recommended, since it costs you less then. 
After that, I added even more and my complex consists now of the following:

- 4x Ranch M
- 1x Cahoona Press M
- 1x Cahoona Press L
- 1x Solar Power Plant
- 3x Mosquito Factory
- 2x Shied Factory 1MJ

Works quite well :).

Comment: I doubt the Euro is the currency of choice in the X3 Universe :)

Comment: Heh, yeah, but I see credits always as a placeholder for any currency and it does not alter the core of the question :p.

Comment: FYI you are wrong about the solar power plant.  Yes buying one costs 2.6m (a large one can cost up to 10m), but it requires crystals as input, and crystals require more food production as well as silicion.  A complete self sufficient energy cell loop will easily run you 10-20 mill

Comment: I planned on buying Ore and Silicium with 2 TraderShips with Jumpdrives. It is not meant to be self sufficient to keep the AI Industry at work.

Comment: A factory has to be within 20km of the thing it is joining to. That means the first two factories must be within 20km of each oter, but any further factories join to the complex hub and so could be up to 40km from each other so long as each one is within 20km of the complex hub. And yes, it is possible to daisy chain hubs together :) And your approach is good. Mosquitos (like 1Mj shields and IREs) sell immensely fast and you won't even need your own selling ships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first complex in the game, I would highly recommend something simpler and only requires energy cells.  There are several that will meet the qualifications, but the best approach is....

***DRUG TRAFFIKING!***

It seems that the inhabitants of the galaxy are highly thirsty and entertainment deprived and will easily gobble up any amount of space weed or space fuel that you can produce at a station.  On top of that, the entire 'loop' for space fuel and space weed consists of only two stations and will only require energy for input:

Space Fuel:

- Argon Wheat Farm
- Argon Space Fuel Distillery

A medium space fuel complex will cost roughly 2.7 million while a large will run you 6.7 million.

Space Weed:

- Teladi Dream Farm
- Teladi Bliss Place

A medium space weed complex will cost ~2 million where a large one will cost 4.5 million.

Keep in mind that both of these factory types are illegal.  Space fuel is illegal everywhere except unowned sectors (I recommend setting one up in that sector between Montalaar and New Income as there are silicon asteroids there as well for you to expand into a full complex at a later point).

However, space weed is legal in all Teladi space, and there is a very nice Teladi sector near the center of the galaxy called Homily of Perpetuity that already has 4 solar power plants, making this the perfect place to start a weed complex.

All you have to do next is to set your complex's sell price to average - 1 and watch a steady stream of NPC ships line up to buy from you.

> Can anyone recommend that approach?

Your complex looks fine, as long as it has a steady supply of energy cells I see no problems with it.

> How far/close from/to each other do I have to build the factories in order to make them a complex?

Ideally, you will want to space out your factories far enough that they do not 'rub' against each other, which will cause your factories to explode spectacularly after a few minutes.  I've found that the minimum distance typically is around 1.5-2km between them, but a complex construction kit can bridge distances much further than that.

There is also a trick with the complex construction kit you can use to string out your complex to as far as you want.  Even if a bunch of your factories are all too far from each other, what you can do is make two complexes and place the hub within 10km of each other, then you can use a complex construction kit to bridge those complexes together.  Using this trick, you can do some crazy things, such as linking together all the asteroids in Savage Spur.

Comment: Nice summary, thanks. But I read about it before and have decided against for now, since it is risky for Space Fuel and I do not have the standing with the Teladi to buy the stations.

Comment: space fuel is not that risky, no one will ever bother you if you set one up in an unowned sector, if you decide not to pursue it, I'd recommend a 1mj shield complex instead as those also sell like hot cakes.

Comment: I looked into it, too much Pirates and Xenon Q's down there and I cannot afford multiple squads to protect everything. So it is not really advisable as a beginner. I built what I mentioned above and gonna add more ammo factories to it until I get a steady income of more than 1 mil per hour.

Comment: it really depends on what sector you choose, there are many unowned sector that is not near pirates/xenon sectors at all.

Comment: I have looked at the sector you told me. However, my question was about the setup I already made.

Comment: Nice. It isn't easy finding info on daisy chaining complex hubs.
For manual layout optimization in X3 Terran Conflict, I used the Factory Complex Constructor scripts. 
https://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=219504
I used the script to build and reorient my complex hub and stations, and connected them the old fashioned way using complex construction kits